# Where to find a usb dongle with both copy protection and storage?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, copy-protection, dongle

We are currently protecting our software with a USB dongle, but we would like also to store the application itself on it. I'm sure something like this exists, but we haven't be able to find it.

Answer (score 9):

It took about 2 minutes on Google to find [the Dinkey FD dongle](http://www.microcosm.co.uk/dinkey_fd.php). I'm sure there are others. It took two more minutes to find somebody claiming a crack. I don't know your market, but make sure it is worth the effort: most of these schemes just annoy your legitimate customers without preventing people who are determined to copy your code.